# Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection and SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: appium, appium-android

When running the appium script, it throws the exception:

```
Unable to create new remote session
```

even if I  override its session on the appium settings.
I am giving the URL and other parameters to the script by having configuration.properties.

Android Studio Log:

```
file path: 
C:\Users\ab.chauhan\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumHJ\app\configs\Configuration.properties
Inside application handling constructor
C:\Users\ab.chauhan\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumHJ\app\FrameworkReports\11_Jan_2019
file path: C:\Users\ab.chauhan\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumHJ\app\configs\Configuration.properties
Inside application handling constructor
C:\Users\ab.chauhan\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumHJ\app\FrameworkReports\11_Jan_2019Before Suite Execution started
Driver:null
URL:http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
cap: Capabilities [{appPackage=cfg.getAppPackage(), appActivity=cfg.getAppActivity(), noReset=true, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=7.0 NRD90M, automationName=uiautomator2, platformName=Android, deviceName=Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 Android 7.0, API 23}]
Jan 11, 2019 6:40:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 11, 2019 6:40:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Jan 11, 2019 6:40:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage=cfg.getAppPackage(), appActivity=cfg.getAppActivity(), noReset=true, newCommandTimeout=4000, platformVersion=7.0 NRD90M, automationName=uiautomator2, platformName=Android, deviceName=Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 Android 7.0, API 23}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'GSG1PM-FT0384', ip: '10.10.23.99', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_152-release'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Appium Script:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 Android 7.0, API 23");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "4000");
cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.0 NRD90M");
cap.setCapability("automationName", cfg.getAutomationName());
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"cfg.getAppPackage()");
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "cfg.getAppActivity()");
System.out.println("Before Suite Execution started");
System.out.println("Driver:"+driver);
System.out.println("URL:"+cfg.getApplicationUrl());
System.out.println("cap: "+cap);
try{
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(cfg.getApplicationUrl()), cap);
System.out.println(driver);}
catch(MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();}
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Your print statement shows you are attempting to access a selenium server at http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub, which is not routable.  The server might bind to 0.0.0.0 (which means all interfaces). but you must access it with a real IP (like 127.0.0.1 if its local, or the real IP if remote)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in the capabilities you have set.

You need to modify these lines from your capabilities,

```
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"cfg.getAppPackage()");
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "cfg.getAppActivity()");
```

To,

```
cap.setCapability (AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, cfg.getAppPackage());
cap.setCapability (AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, cfg.getAppActivity());
```

Actually you called your method inside quotes which should not be done. Call it directly as you did for `URL` and `AutomationName`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Issue resolved by reinstalling the "io.appium.setting & unlock.apk " Plus changing the capabilities. (for my case)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Jan 11, 2019 6:40:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession 
 INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end 
Jan 11, 2019 6:40:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession 
 INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol. 
Jan 11, 2019 6:40:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession 
 INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.
```

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.

...implies that the **AndroidDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Remote Session**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using **java.version** **`1.8.0_152-release`** which is pretty old and ancient.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: any evidence that the issue is the Java version?  This sounds like a speculative troubleshooting tip rather than a valid answer.